# ldap_modify: No such object (32)

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I installed OpenLDAP on Centos 7 and tried to create the admin user. But I got some error on `ldap_modify`. Below are my steps:

Install OpenLDAP and start it:

```
sudo yum install openldap openldap-servers openldap-clients -y
systemctl start slapd.service
```

Create `admin.ldif`

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}CRiUMh5UM8/chPHbfc2Se2JA8Quc5F1P

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth"
  read by dn.base="cn=ldapadmin,dc=demo,dc=local" read by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=demo,dc=local

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=ldapadmin,dc=demo,dc=local

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}CRiUMh5UM8/chPHbfc2Se2JA8Quc5F1P

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by
  dn="cn=ldapadmin,dc=demo,dc=local" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=ldapadmin,dc=demo,dc=local" write by * read
```

Run below command line:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /root/demo/users/admin.ldif
```

Then I got this **error**:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
    matched DN: cn=config
```

I didn't have this error in a different system using Centos 7 so I am wondering what's happening here.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Here is the fix:

Change `olcDatabase={2}bdb` to `olcDatabase={2}hdb`

Make sure run these beforehand:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif 
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

Reference: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html